# Overlaying two AmCharts

Tags: javascript, d3.js, amcharts

I have one chart I want to build that has a scatter plot and then four lines. The four lines will be from a completely different dataset, with the same x min max and y min max but different structure. How can I create one chart with the fixed xmin xmax ymin ymax and then another and have one overlay the other.

Basically I want one chart with two completely different datasets that have the same domain and ranges AND keep the interactivity of both. I am trying the datasets an field mappings but haven't had much luck. I am not entirely sure I understand what the field mappings are doing. An example I found:

```
  "dataSets": [ {
    "title": "first data set",
    "fieldMappings": [ {
      "fromField": "value",
      "toField": "value"
  }, {
      "fromField": "volume",
      "toField": "volume"
  } ],
    "dataProvider": chartData1,
    "categoryField": "date"
}, {
    "title": "second data set",
    "fieldMappings": [ {
      "fromField": "value",
      "toField": "value"
  }, {
      "fromField": "volume",
      "toField": "volume"
  } ],
    "dataProvider": chartData2,
    "categoryField": "date"
}],
```

I am using dataloader for now, I am able to read in both datasets at one time with ajax as another option if I can do it all in one chart. So I am not sure how to use dataloader with this example either. So if someone knows how that may work that would be helpful as well.

Thanks!

Comment: Did it help solve your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

D3 should be able to handle that pretty easily. You can use d3.request (e.g. d3.json) to call the data (in separate requests if necessary). Then d3.scale to set your min/max values to defined points on an svg chart, then plot your scatter points/lines etc. to those points using the data requested.

Mess about with axes and tooltips for a bit and you should have a functional chart.

Answer (score 1):

### You can use simple CSS to get that.

`position: absolute`, some positioning coordinates `top` & `left`, and dimentions `width` & `height`.

`z-index` to decide what would be on top of what.

And transparent background for both of them.

The rest is just configurations in the config JSON of the chart.

```js
AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
  "type": "serial",
 "autoMargins": false,
 "marginBottom": 0,
 "marginLeft": 0,
 "marginRight": 0,
 "marginTop": 0,
  "categoryField": "category",
  "startDuration": 1,
  "categoryAxis": {
    "gridPosition": "start"
  },
  "trendLines": [],
  "graphs": [{
      "fillAlphas": 1,
      "fillColors": "#4DCD11",
      "balloonText": "[[title]] of [[category]]:[[value]]",
      "fillAlphas": 1,
      "id": "AmGraph-1",
      "title": "graph 1",
      "type": "column",
      "valueField": "column-1"
    },
    {
      "fillAlphas": 1,
      "fillColors": "#070AB5",
      "balloonText": "[[title]] of [[category]]:[[value]]",
      "fillAlphas": 1,
      "id": "AmGraph-2",
      "title": "graph 2",
      "type": "column",
      "valueField": "column-2"
    }
  ],
  "guides": [],
  "allLabels": [],
  "balloon": {},
  "titles": [{
    "id": "Title-1",
    "size": 15,
    "text": " "
  }],
  "dataProvider": [{
      "category": "1",
      "column-1": 8,
      "column-2": 5
    },
    {
      "category": "2",
      "column-1": 6,
      "column-2": 7
    },
    {
      "category": "3",
      "column-1": 2,
      "column-2": 3
    }
  ]
});

AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv2", {
  "type": "serial",
  "theme": "light",
 "autoMargins": false,
 "marginBottom": 0,
 "marginLeft": 0,
 "marginRight": 0,
 "marginTop": 0,
  "categoryField": "category",
  "startDuration": 1,
  "categoryAxis": {
    "gridPosition": "start"
  },
  "trendLines": [],
  "graphs": [{
      "balloonText": "[[title]] of [[category]]:[[value]]",
      "id": "AmGraph-1",
      "lineThickness": 6,
      "noStepRisers": true,
      "title": "graph 1",
      "type": "step",
      "valueField": "column-1"
    },
    {
      "balloonText": "[[title]] of [[category]]:[[value]]",
      "id": "AmGraph-2",
      "lineThickness": 6,
      "noStepRisers": true,
      "title": "graph 2",
      "type": "step",
      "valueField": "column-2"
    }
  ],
  "guides": [],
  "valueAxes": [{
    "id": "ValueAxis-1",
    "title": " "
  }],
  "allLabels": [],
  "balloon": {},
  "titles": [{
    "id": "Title-1",
    "size": 15,
    "text": " "
  }],
  "dataProvider": [{
      "category": "1",
      "column-1": 8,
      "column-2": 5
    },
    {
      "category": "2",
      "column-1": 6,
      "column-2": "2"
    },
    {
      "category": "3",
      "column-1": "7",
      "column-2": 3
    },
    {
      "category": "4",
      "column-1": "9",
      "column-2": 3
    },
    {
      "category": "5",
      "column-1": "7",
      "column-2": 1
    },
    {
      "category": "6",
      "column-1": "8",
      "column-2": 2
    },
    {
      "category": "7",
      "column-1": "7",
      "column-2": "6"
    }
  ]
});
```

```css
#chartdiv,
#chartdiv2 {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: transparent;
}

#chartdiv {
  z-index: 100;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 600px;
  height: 400px
}

#chartdiv2 {
  z-index: 120;
  top: 120px;
  left: 100px;
  width: 400px;
  height: 180px
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amcharts.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/serial.js"></script>
<div id="chartdiv"></div>
<div id="chartdiv2"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks! I will try it now it looks like it is exactly what I am looking for though

Comment: Please accept the answer if you think that was helpful, or edit the question :)

Comment: SO I tried it, but not exactly what I wanted. I think I will edit the question, because I still want the interactivity.